# which is correct way to use navigate dependency in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I use useEffect in App.tsx

```
import { useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const dispatch = useDispatch()
const navigate = useNavigate()
useEffect(() => {
    const jwt = storage.getToken()
    if(jwt) {
      dispatch(asyncInit())
      navigate('/profile')
    }
  }, [])
```

Without dependency dispatch and navigate React App shows a warning. But I can't put dispatch and navigate into dependency cuz every time redirect user to /profile navigate change state, this component rerender and it keep redirect to /profile/

Comment: could you provide more information about `dispatch` and `navigate` methods?

Comment: @hgb123 I updated my code. Can you take a look please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right we can't put everything we use in dependency array so what you can do is put

```
 //eslint-disable-next-line
```

above the dependency array. It will stop giving you warnings and there's nothing wrong with doing it.

```
import { useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const dispatch = useDispatch()
const navigate = useNavigate()
useEffect(() => {
    const jwt = storage.getToken()
    if(jwt) {
      dispatch(asyncInit())
      navigate('/profile')
    }
//eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm feel so wrong to do that but I'll :D

Comment: I felt the same when I started doing that. But it's the only way I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue in my application and thought that it would be safe to ignore that warning, but looks like it is not. Since it changes the state (navigate), the hook will use its version from previous render. I think this might cause some issues later, not sure.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies